# ReactJS counter or timer with Start or Stop Button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, counter, use-state

Need help to understand in useEffect, if I don't put counter and timerCheck in useEffect dependency then what it will effect here.
And if I put timerCheck dependency in useEffect then counter increasing 100 time faster

Also how can i run this code without any error or warning

[code in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-gauss-nqf30c?file=/src/App.js:103-770)

```
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  const [startcounter, setStartcounter] = useState(false);
  const [timerCheck, setTimerCheck] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    let intervalStart = null;
    if (startcounter) {
      intervalStart = setInterval(() => {
        setCounter((prevState) => (prevState += 1));
      }, 1000);
      setTimerCheck(intervalStart);
    } else {
      clearInterval(timerCheck);
    }

    return () => {
      if (counter !== 0) clearInterval(timerCheck);
    };
  }, [startcounter]);

  const handleStartButton = () => {
    setStartcounter(true);
  };

  const handleStopButton = () => {
    setStartcounter(false);
  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try not to declare unnecessary states. `timerCheck` state is redundant.

1. You want to start an interval that increases counter by one every second.
2. When user stops the stopwatch , you want the interval to be cleared, so it would stop increasing the `timer`.

So your only dependancy in `useEffect` would be whether your stopwatch is running or not. And the only thing that matters to you, is when `startCounter` is `ture`. You start an interval when it is true and clear the interval in its cleanup.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    let intervalStart = null;

    if (!startcounter) {
      return () => {};
    }

    intervalStart = setInterval(() => {
      setCounter((prevState) => (prevState += 1));
    }, 1000);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(intervalStart);
    };
  }, [startcounter]);
```

Here is the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-cookies-6bfqx1?file=/src/App.js)

**But you do not really need `useEffect` for this**. IMO it would be a much better code without using `useEffect`.

Answer (score 0):

So useEffect with no dependency will run on every render.

If you include a dependency, it will re-render and run whenever that dependency changes. So by including `timerCheck` in it, you're telling the page to re-render whenever that changes, which ends up changing it, causing it to re-render again, causing it to change again, etc., etc.

More info: https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_useeffect.asp

Comment: Exactly I am facing that issue. So in the above program how would I run without error or warning. would you please help